# mysql and event scheduling at wrong time

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I've set up an event in mysql to run every 24 hours starting 'tomorrow'. That's whats the event table is showing:

```
db  name    body            definer     execute_at  interval_value  interval_field  created                 modified                last_executed           starts ...
DBA P1      [BLOB - 51 B]   abc@%       NULL        24              HOUR            2014-02-01 15:10:19     2014-02-01 15:10:19     2014-02-01 16:08:14     2014-02-02 14:10:19
```

What's making trouble is, that allthough it should start on `2014-02-02 14:10:19` it has already executed on `2014-02-01 16:08:14` which isn't even 24 hours from the creation time?

What's wrong, any ideas?

This is the create statement:

```
CREATE EVENT `P1` 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR 
  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 HOUR 
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO ..some sql...
```

Comment: everything looks right.  Is it possible that you ran it w/o the delay once?

Comment: no, it has been set up straight away like it is.

Comment: hmmm... I had a previous definition of that event with a two hours recurring time, but I deleted that and created new from scratch. can it be that this "schedule" still was running and triggered the new event with the same name?

Comment: I think you found it :)  Yes.

Comment: But that actualy would mean to get unpredictable side effects. Supposed I delete an event, schedule a new one withe something completely different at another time but with the same name would mean that this event will be executed at the old schedule? How can I prevent this, since even restarting the event thread doesn't stop that?

Comment: I don't think so.  I think it just thinks this even ran in the past, because of the name.  Just like when you modify an events actions, it will not change the history of runs.